# Compatibility - my website have some issues with mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, mobile

This is my [website](https://jsfiddle.net/f8zu09ex/3/), Which should let the user draw with the mouse on the canvas. It works fine on Chrome desktop browser but if I try to do that on mobile an error pop up on the console saying something like

```
index.js:95 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined
    at HTMLCanvasElement.<anonymous> (index.js:95)
```

**Reporting the following code:**

```
el.addEventListener("touchend", function (e) {
        var touch = e.touches[0];
        var mouseEvent = new MouseEvent("mouseup", {
            clientX: touch.clientX,
            clientY: touch.clientY
        });
```

I really don't know what to do, I believe that the problem is with my jquery, I thought to create something to let the user drag the page with two fingers and draw with one but the only thing that I got was errors.

Comment: on `touchend` the finger does not touch the device, so the `touches` is empty (*if you have lifted all fingers*). See the `changedTouches` property of the event.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong event property. You need to query e.changedTouches and not e.touches:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/changedTouches

Hope this helps.